# LWC get url parameters in Community

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, code, developer

I'm trying to retrieve url parameters through a lightning web component in my Community.

For exemple :
wwww.my-community.com/my-page?**test=true**

How can I, in the new LWC framework, get the parameter "test" and it's value ?

Thanks for your answers ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the question was if the LWC Framework provide an utility - then no not that i am aware of.

Which means you can use every js snippet you will find somewhere in the web like

```
    parameters = {};

    connectedCallback() {

        this.parameters = this.getQueryParameters();
        console.log(this.parameters);
    }

    getQueryParameters() {

        var params = {};
        var search = location.search.substring(1);

        if (search) {
            params = JSON.parse('{"' + search.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"') + '"}', (key, value) => {
                return key === "" ? value : decodeURIComponent(value)
            });
        }

        return params;
    }
```

That will return you an key/value pair of your parameters for further usage in your component

Comment: Thank you ! :) It works :) I used another script in js because LWC do not have a native function

Comment: Don't forget that only paramters with names starting with "c__" will be kept in the location.href

Comment: VF pages could receive GET/POST Request parameters and read by Apex, Just wondering how LWC cater this?

Answer (score 16):

Another approach with using [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams):

> The **searchParams** readonly property of the URL interface returns a URLSearchParams object allowing access to the GET decoded query arguments contained in the URL.

```js
connectedCallback() {
    const param = 'test';
    const paramValue = this.getUrlParamValue(window.location.href, param);
}

getUrlParamValue(url, key) {
    return new URL(url).searchParams.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The best way to get params from URL is use **CurrentPageRefference**.

currentPageReference.state allows you to get params.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class Test extends LightningElement {

    currentPageReference = null; 
    urlStateParameters = null;

    urlId = null;
    urlLanguage = null;
    urlType = null;

    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
       if (currentPageReference) {
          this.urlStateParameters = currentPageReference.state;
          this.setParametersBasedOnUrl();
       }
    }

    setParametersBasedOnUrl() {
       this.urlId = this.urlStateParameters.id || null;
       this.urlLanguage = this.urlStateParameters.lang || null;
       this.urlType = this.urlStateParameters.type || '10';
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

More details you can find here
https://beyondthecloud.dev/blog/get-url-parameters-in-lwc

Comment: Note that the state property is not available in Experience Cloud sites: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation.

Comment: @Vincent https://salesforceprofs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/image-1024x325.png

Please check the image above.
 
The state is available in Experience Cloud sites. I was using this solution with many Experience Clouds projects and there was no problem with it. 

What is in your link:
**Note: Experience Builder sites don't support the state property.** 
Experience Builder is part of Experience Cloud and is for set up the pages, not for users, so it's not relevant.